# Type-safely create instance of Function to be passed to Comparator.comparing()

Tags: java

Assume I have a method with the following signature:

```java
<T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> method(Map<String, Function<? super T, ? extends U>> comparatorFunctionMap)
```

The method accepts a map of functions (with string keys) and creates a `Comparator<T>` as a result (it isn't important how). Map values are instances of `Function<? super T, ? extends U>`, so that they can be directly passed to `Comparator.comparing()`.

How do I populate this map in a type-safe way? Say I have a class `Person` with attributes `name` and `age` (and getters for them).

When I do the following:

```java
Map<String, Function<? super Person, ? extends Comparable>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("name", Person::getName);
method(map1);
```

I get a warning on lines 1 and 3. If I try this instead, for example:

```java
Map<String, Function<? super Person, ? extends Comparable<?>>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map2.put("name", Person::getName);
method(map2);
```

The third line is a compile error.

Is there a way to do this type-safely?

Comment: I don't get any warning using your first snippet (raw Comparable).

Comment: Do you need the functions in your map to be able to return more than one type?  e.g., does the same map need to be able to hold a `Function<Person, String>` and a `Function<Person, Integer>` ?

Comment: @MikeStrobel: Yes, the idea was to allow different comparable types (at least strings and numbers but perhaps others as well) together in the map. I see now this is the main issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to add both `Person::getName` and `Person::getAge` in the map, you won't be able to use the method signature you propose because there is no U that is a supertype of both String, Integer and Comparable.

Essentially, your map is a `Map<String, Function<T, Comparable<?>>` since the comparables are not related to each other type-wise.

I don't think you can get around it without using raw types, which could look like below. Note that you still have type safety (you must pass a `Comparable` to the map).

```
static void m() {
  Map<String, Function<Person, Comparable<?>>> map = new HashMap<>();
  map.put("name", Person::getName);
  map.put("age", Person::getAge);
  Comparator<Person> c = method(map);
}


@SuppressWarnings(value = {"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
static <T> Comparator<T> method(String name, Map<String, Function<T, Comparable<?>>> comparatorFunctionMap) {
  Function f = (Function) comparatorFunctionMap.get("age");
  Comparator<T> c = Comparator.comparing(f);
  return c;
}
```

The only (I think) limitation of this is that technically, one could pass a weird class say `Weird implements Comparable<String>` that would probably cause a runtime error.

Comment: I would assume `getName()` returns a `String`, which does not fit the constraint `Comparable<? super Person>`.

Comment: @assylias: Thanks, I had a feeling the problem was trying to fit functions returning different comparable types into a common collection but couldn't properly express it.